# How to convert mm:ss time string to seconds integer (postgres/liquibase)

Tags: java, postgresql, liquibase

Here is the situation:
- I have a spring boot app handling short videos.
- Upon its start it uses liquibase and has some changelogs altering db structure etc. There is a posgresql db underneath. There is less than 20k records/year.
- I have previously collected data containing recording duration in string format MM:SS
- video engine is about to change to one that stores recording duration in a single number representing seconds
- I figured to make more changelogs handling such operations:

> create another column for seconds
>   convert MM:SS string to second and store it in the new column
>   remove old column and rename the new one

The biggest problem is to make a conversion query with simple calculation inside. After using some answers below I ended up with this:

```
update recording set duration_seconds = case when duration ~ ':'
    then (60 * CAST (substr(duration, 1, position((':' - 1) in duration)) AS integer)) + (CAST (substr(duration, position((':' +1) in duration)) AS integer))
    else 60 * CAST (duration AS integer)
END
```

but still get the error

```
[org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml::20200430_covert_time_string_to_seconds::xxxxxxxxxxxx:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: syntax error at or near ","
```

Answer (score 1):

The number of seconds in 1 hour and 5 min:

```
select extract(epoch from time '01:05') as time_sec -- 3900 = 1 * 60 * 60 + 5 * 60
```

If you have the seconds part:

```
select extract(epoch from time '01:05:01') as time_sec -- 3901
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a conflict is your description. You say you have a text column in format MM:SS, but then your conversion plan is to convert HH:MM. The conversion for these formats will be quite different. Even more so if its HH:MM:SS. 
Assuming your format is MM:SS does that indicate 2hrs is recorded as 120 or 120:00. If that's the case extracting the epoch is likely to fail. The following would work.

```
set new_duration = case when duration ~ ':' 
                        then 
                           60*(substr(duration,1,position(duration,':'-1)::integer
                             +(substr(duration,position(duration,':'+1)::integer
                        else 
                           60*duration::integer
```

Additionally you need to add a step to your plan to validate that column is properly formatted in every row. IMHO there is no such thing as a date time value stored in text (string); yes there are strings that with hope and good luck contain the proper formatted data - don't count on it.